# Объект в массиве или непонятный вид конструкций

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Непонятное "сооружение". Как получить из этого объекта элементы?
И вообще, что это такое?
 `[]{0:0, 1:1 ...}.`
 Как создавать такие конструкции в ручную?

[image: --]

[image: --]

Comment: А что выдает конструкция `typeof`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там чёрным по белому написано "HTMLCollection". Это массив с элементами на странице. Как вы его создаёте можно глянуть только в коде. :) Скорее всего багнулся браузер и не подписал сверху ***HTMLCollection[10]***

Получить можно например так:

```
[document.getElementsByClassName('row')]
```